# To parse text file and create json out of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I want to parse a text file in which the first row contains the headers and are the keys and the next row(2nd row) has its corresponding values.

The problem I'm facing is that the content in the text file is not symmetric meaning there are uneven spaces between the first and the second row so, I'm not able to use the delimiter also.

Also, there is no necessity that the header will always have a corresponding value in the next row. It may be empty sometimes.

After that, I want to make it a JSON format having those key-value pairs.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import re
with open("E:\\wipro\\samridh\\test.txt") as read_file:
    line = read_file.readline()

    while line:

        #print(line,end='')
        new_string = re.sub(' +',' ', line)
        line= read_file.readline()

    print(new_string)
```

PFA image of my text input

[image]

Comment: Please post your text data as text in your question. It makes it easier to copy and paste.

Comment: Your text file seems to be a fixed width format. Just take substrings from each line and strip whitespace from the end. No need for a regex.

Comment: At least a part of it (if possible). And not in a IMAGE format. Makes it impossible to copy paste.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I have the feeling the column widths will change depending on the data, so what works for that particular file might fail miserably in the future.

Comment: @AKX, not if you derive the column widths from the header.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Sure, but that's worth spelling out too. :)

Comment: @BartFriederichs I am not able to post the text data as the site is not including the uneven whitespaces,

Answer (score 1):

You can find the indices and matches of the header with the `finditer` of the `re` package. Then, use that to process the rest:

```
import re
import json

thefile = open("file.txt")

line = thefile.readline()
iter = re.finditer("\w+\s+", line)
columns = [(m.group(0), m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in iter]
records = []
while line:
    line = thefile.readline()

    record = {}
    for col in columns:
        record[col[0]] = line[col[1]:col[2]]
        records.append(record)

print(json.dumps(records))
```

I'll leave it up to OP to strip whitespace and filter out empty entries. Not to mention error handling ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to do, but if I understand it correctly and under these assumptions: - you only have 2 lines in the file. - you have the same number of keys and value. - no spaces allowed "inside" a value or key, meaning no spaces allowed except the ones separate between elements.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

after that, `content[0]` is your keys line and `content[1]` is your values.

now all you need to do is this:

```
key_value_dict = {}
for key,value in zip(content[0].split(), content[1].split()):
     key_value_dict[key] = value
```

and your key_value_dict holds up a dictionary (JSON like) of keys and values.

Comment: Would the above work considering the second row has values that have spaces in between them?  The split arrays will have different number of elements.

Comment: you can try this code and find out, but the quick answer is - yes , i will explain: since I called `spit` with no arguments the default is splitting by all kind and number of spaces , so assuming that the number of keys and values are the same (as I wrote in my answer) , and they are separated with any amount of spaces between then - yes it will work . OP if answer helped you please accept.

Comment: He has values which are inside of double quotes, e.g. “Supports Writing”.  If you split by spaces, one value will be split into two and therefore the number of headers wont equal the number values.

Comment: you are right and I edited my answer and added this condition to the assumptions, all OP need to do is delete the spaces in `{"Supports Writing"...}` and replace that with a dash or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each of the headers is a single word without intervening whitespace. Then, to find out where each column starts, you can do this, for example:

```
with open("E:\\wipro\\samridh\\test.txt") as read_file:
   line = next(read_file)
   headers = line.split()
   l_bounds = [line.find(word) for word in headers]
```

When splitting data lines, you will also need the right boundaries. If you know, say, that none of your data lines is longer than 1000 characters, you could do something like this:

```
r_bounds = l_bounds[1:] + [1000]
```

When you walk over the data lines, you put together the left and right limits and the header_words like so:

```
out_str = json.dumps({name: line[l:r].strip() 
                      for name, l, r in zip(headers, l_bounds, r_bounds)})
```

No regex required, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Assumptions the below makes:

- Headers are one word (as they are in your example)
- Headers and values don’t overlap... That is if header 1 goes from index 5 to 15, then its value in the row below will also be found within the same index of the row below

Benefits of this approach are that the values can have spaces in between them (as they do in your example).  If you were to split both the header and value strings by spaces, then they would have a different number of elements and you wouldn’t be able to combine them.  Also, you wouldn’t be able to find values that were empty (as in his example).

Here is the approach I would take...

If you are sure your file headers are only one words (no spaces), then find all indices of the first character of each word and store them in an array.  Every time you figure out two indices, extract the header between them. So between (header1-firstchar, header2-firstchar - 1)...

Then get the second line and sequentially extract substrings from indices: (header1-firstchar, header2-firstchar - 1)...

Once you've done that combine the extracted header/key and values into a dictionary.

```
dictVerson = zip(headers, values)
```

Then call following:

```
import json

jsonVersion = json.dumps(dictVersion)
```